# C++ ifstream read 2 character numbers

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, k , i, j, mic;
    char results[100], read[100];
    ifstream averiin;
    ofstream averiout("averi.out");
    averiin.open("averi.in", ifstream::in);
    averiin>>n>>k;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        averiin>>read[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++) {
            if(read[i] > read[j]) {
                mic = read[j];
                read[j] = read[i];
                read[i] = mic;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<k;i++) {
        results[i] = read[i];
        averiout<<results[i];
        cout<<results[i]<<" ";
    }
    averiout.close();
    getchar();
}
```

If I want to read for example: 20 12 25 36 2 67, what I need to change to read the 2 character numbers?
This code reads one by one... :(

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the format of input file (`averi.in`). It's hard to guess what needs to change without it.

Comment: 8(n) 3(k)
2 1 8 5 9 3 4 7(if are only 1 character, works) but if they are like this:  " 23 12 92 94 ...", reads one by one...read[0] = 2, read[1] = 3, read[2] = 1...

Comment: @WoaDmulL Will the numbers have mixed amounts of digits? Can they have more than 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of `read` to array of int's and it should work (results probably also needs to be changed to array of ints).